# How to create temporal routes for testing in Foxx?

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to add some tests to my Foxx app. At the moment, I need to recreate a new route for every test case in Mocha like so:

```
it('allows POST with JSON encoding', function() {
  var app = new Foxx.Controller(applicationContext);

  app.post(urlString(), graphqlHTTP({
    schema: TestSchema
  }));

  var res = request(app).post(urlString(), {
    body: { query: '{test}' },
    json: true
  });

  expect(res.text).to.equal('{"data":{"test":"Hello World"}}');
});
```

And I have a problem with this line `var app = new Foxx.Controller(applicationContext);` when I run testing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at new Controller (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/foxx/controller.js:330:19)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/var/lib/arangodb-apps/_db/ilearn/my-app/APP/src/__tests__/http-test.js:328:17)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:233:15)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:390:10)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at /usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:473:12
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at next (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:315:14)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at /usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:325:7
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at next (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:260:23)
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at /usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/node/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:292:5
2016-02-14T12:58:58Z [12527] INFO /my-app     at Function.global.DEFINE_MODULE.exports.nextTick (/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/2.8.0/share/arangodb/js/common/bootstrap/modules/process.js:26:3)
```

... which is basically says that `applicationContext.foxxes` is `undefined`.

I also understand that it is not very wise to use global `applicationContext` for testing. But how can I create my own? I have not found any documentation on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArangoDB 2.x it's not possible to create controllers dynamically. Controllers can only be created in files loaded via the `controllers` property in the Foxx service manifest. Although they look like regular objects, as you have noticed, they actually manipulate the magical `applicationContext.foxxes` property which is defined at load time and then read when the module has been executed.

This means there's no way to use `Foxx.Controller` dynamically in your tests. You can however access the mount point of your service with `applicationContext.mount` and construct URLs pointing at your real controllers this way.

In ArangoDB 3.0 it will be possible to create routers (which are the equivalent of 2.x controllers) dynamically although there is no instrumentalisation to mount them dynamically in tests or to send fake requests to them.

Your example looks like it is actually testing a GraphQL schema rather than the controller itself. In that case you could simply write a test that passes the query to the schema and test its output directly.

Alternatively you could extract the callback you pass as the request handler into a separate function and test its behaviour using fake request and response objects.

A full-stack integration test that goes through ArangoDB's HTTP stack should probably be the last resort for Foxx tests. Aside from the obvious performance problems (tying up at least two threads for the duration of the request plus actually having to hit the request/response overhead itself) it can also result in unexpected behaviour if your service is running in development mode (i.e. the incoming request might cause the service to reload while the test is still running).

As a side note, it's perfectly acceptable to use `applicationContext` in files other than the controllers, scripts and exports. The context is always relative to the file and not directly shared by the entire service (although it mostly just wraps properties of the service itself, making it appear global to all files of the service). So for the most part you can use it in testing as long as you don't directly manipulate e.g. the configuration or manifest properties.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. I want to port `express-graphql` package to Foxx, in order to make Graphql to work really stable with ArangoDB. There is a lot of testing of GET, POST requests and different kinds of possible inputs. So I'm thinking, that the best solution might be is to run tests separately with Mocha over NodeJS. The Foxx app will not contain any tests but will only use the actual code of the package to serve the server with some URL endpoint for testing. I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: @artnikpro I think the best approach would be to to implement it as a function that takes the controller and path and then invokes `ctrl.post(path, fn)` with the request handler function (and then adds the apropriate params and such). This way you don't need to test with a real controller, you can just check that it correctly attaches itself and then check the behaviour of the request handler.

Comment: @artnikpro Also remember to use `graphql-sync` as the `graphql` module doesn't work in ArangoDB (it requires using promises which only work in async environments).